# Scheme function with one parameter that will swap every two elements

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

```
(define (interchange list) 
    (if (empty? list)
        list
        (interchange (append (car (cdr list) X)))))
```

I need to create a function that swaps the pairs of elements in a scheme list. This is what I have come up with so far but I get error with the `empty?`

```
Error
empty?: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier

function call                                       output
(interchange '( ))                                  ()
(interchange '(a))                                  (a)
(interchange '(a  b))                               (b a)
(interchange '(a  b  c))                            (b a c)
(interchange '(a  1  b  2  c  3  d  4))             (1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d)
(interchange '(hello  you  -12.34  5  -6  enough))  (you hello 5 -12.34 enough -6)
```

Comment: What language is this written in? `#lang racket`? `#lang scheme`? `#lang r5rs`?

Comment: #lang scheme @AlexisKing

Comment: Is it `scheme` or `scheme/base`? The former should have `empty?`, but `racket/base` and `scheme/base` don't provide it.

Comment: @AlexisKing it should be scheme. I have dr. Racket running on 6.1.

Comment: Please show an example of what you want to do. At least post sample input, expected output for two lists, one with an odd number of elements and other with an even number of elements

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I have added expected inputs and output

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
(define (interchange lst)
  (if (or (null? lst) (null? (cdr lst)))       ; if the list has 0 or 1 elements left
      lst                                      ; then return the list, we're done
      (cons (cadr lst)                         ; otherwise grab the second element
            (cons (car lst)                    ; and the first element
                  (interchange (cddr lst)))))) ; and move forward two elements
```

The trick is to process two elements per iteration, being careful with the edge cases. It works as expected for the sample input:

```
(interchange '())
=> '()
(interchange '(a))
=> '(a)
(interchange '(a  b))
=> '(b a)
(interchange '(a  b  c))
=> '(b a c)
(interchange '(a  1  b  2  c  3  d  4))
=> '(1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d)
(interchange '(hello  you  -12.34  5  -6  enough))
=> '(you hello 5 -12.34 enough -6)
```

Comment: How do I make sure I do that going forward? Do you have any good tutorials? I haven't really found any. Thanks so much.

Comment: There are literally tons of good tutorials and books on internet, personally I'd recommend "The little Schemer" and "How to Design Programs"

Answer (score 2):

```
#lang racket

(define (interchange xs)
  (match xs
    [(or '() (list _))                 ; if the list is empty or has one element
     xs]                               ; then interchange keeps the original list
    [(list* x y more)                  ; if the list has two or more elements,
     (list* y x (interchange more))])) ; then the result consists of the two
;                                      ; first elements (with the order swapped)
;                                      ; followed by the result of 
;                                      ; interchanging the remaining elements.


(interchange '( ))                                 
(interchange '(a))                               
(interchange '(a  b))                              
(interchange '(a  b  c))                           
(interchange '(a  1  b  2  c  3  d  4))            
(interchange '(hello  you  -12.34  5  -6  enough))
```

Output:

```
'()
'(a)
'(b a)
'(b a c)
'(1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d)
'(you hello 5 -12.34 enough -6)
```